# JQuery confusion with each is not working for me

Tags: jquery

```
    <body>

    <div class="container">
    <h1>Write Queries</h1>
    <div id="leftdiv">
    </div>
     <div id="rightdiv">
     <h4>TABLES</h4>
     <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.each demo</title>
  <style>
  div.one {
    color: blue;
  }
  div.two {
    color: red;
    display: none;
  }
  a {
      text-decoration: none;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='one'>department<br></div><div class='two'><input type='checkbox' name='results' class='right_tables'> id<br /><input type='checkbox' name='results' class='right_tables'> dept<br /><input type='checkbox' name='results' class='right_tables'> emp_id<br /></div><div class='one'>hussaib11<br></div><div class='two'><input type='checkbox' name='results' class='right_tables'> id<br /></div><div class='one'>hussaibd11<br></div><div class='two'><input type='checkbox' name='results' class='right_tables'> id<br /></div><div class='one'>company<br></div><div class='two'><input type='checkbox' name='results' class='right_tables'> id<br /><input type='checkbox' name='results' class='right_tables'> name<br /><input type='checkbox' name='results' class='right_tables'> age<br /><input type='checkbox' name='results' class='right_tables'> address<br /><input type='checkbox' name='results' class='right_tables'> salary<br /></div>

</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(document).on("click", '.one',function() {
            $('.two').slideDown(1000);
            });

        $(document).on("click", ".two", function(){
                $('.two').slideUp(5000);
            }); 
        });

</script>
</html>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This piece of code is supposed to response when I click on the div with class one. I have create a function that is going to add a div every time with this class, so there are more than one with the same class, When I click on any div all of the other divs response to the click, but I just want each to response to the click when I do that. How do you go about that? 
The div with .two is hidden with css display none.

Comment: Why do you use `$.click` in `$.each` ?

Comment: @Noel Villaman can you update your html code?

Comment: looks like no need each function. directly use click function without each. use `on' instead of click.

Comment: I added what should happen every time I get some data from the database. Using on is doing the same as before. I click on the first one ".one" class and all the others response too. I want just the one I click to response while the others remain hidden. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that they're all responding to the click, it's that you're telling all the `.two` elements to `slideDown()` whenever any `.one` is clicked. You need to target the specific `.two`. E.g. (assuming the `.two` element immediately follows the `.one`)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('.one').click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideDown(1000);
    });

   $('.two').click(function(){
        $(this).slideUp(5000);
    }); 
});
```

(also, you don't need `each()` - in jQuery, `$('.one').func()` generally means to apply `func()` to all elements with class `.one`, so I removed the `each()`)

Comment: This is the way to go about that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add click event handler by iterating all divs. Just use `.on()` to bind click event for dynamically created divs

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
       $(document).on("click",'.one',function(){
            $(this).next('.two').slideDown(1000);
        });

    $(document).on("click",'.two',function(){
            $(this).slideUp(5000);
     }); 
});
```

Comment: It is still doing the same, all the if I have many with divs with .one class, they all response to the click.

Comment: After looking at the html structure i have updated my answer. please check.